# SQLite join doesnt show nothing

Tags: sqlite

I have this sql statement

```
SELECT a.*, c.* 
FROM ALUMNOS AS a 
JOIN calif AS c 
where a.curp=c.curp
```

If I select individually the data on each table - it is showed, but when I do the join - the results are 0. Can you help me, or you need more information?
Thanks.

Edit: Already sollved, the data it's shown when both tables have at least 1 column with the same id.

Edit 2: I didn't thougt that the statement doesn't show nothing if the joined column has no data. My bad.

Comment: @alex SQLite does not actually need an ON clause.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT curp FROM Alumnos WHERE curp IN (SELECT curp FROM Calif)`?

Comment: @CL. it throw 0 rows

Comment: maybe you just don't have same curp values in two tables. so it works fine (?)

Comment: Are there actually rows that have the same value in both tables?

Comment: Man, I'm a mess, I truncated one of those tables before the test, but forgot to repopulate it, then the statement worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect. What you want is an implicit join

```
SELECT a.*, c.* 
FROM ALUMNOS AS a, calif AS c 
where a.curp=c.curp
```

you can also rewrite it as explicit join:

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
FROM ALUMNOS JOIN CALIF USING (curp)
```

Comment: The query was correct, but since one of the tables had 0 rows, the result was 0 rows. However, thanks.